# SQL schema for daily summaries

Tags: sql, database-design, schema

I've got a database which stores pings from various places in the following format:

```
|    Date    | Source | Language |   OS   | Version | more...
| 2011-10-30 | App1   | en       | XP     | 1.0     | ...
| 2011-10-30 | App2   | de       | 10.7.1 | 1.3     | ...
```

It works just fine for extracting snapshot information. I would like to be able to store daily summaries generated from the above table so that I can get graphs of how the information changes over time.

Examples:

- Graph showing date against version usage
- Graph showing date against OS version

The problem is that several of the columns in the table above (language, os, version) can have a variable number of values. I've not had much of an education in database design and can't get my head around how to store this information for easy retrieval.

Can anyone make any suggestions?

Comment: Was your problem solved? Did you try normalization? I don't see any accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quite easily get those statistics from the current table structure. The SQL keyword [`GROUP BY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) should be your friend.

To get version usage per date you type

```
SELECT Date, Version, count(*) as NumberOfEntries
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Date, Version
ORDER BY Date, Version
```

(The `ORDER BY Date, Version` is just to get a nice sorted output)

If you want to have statistics per each combination of Source and Version you modify the question to

```
SELECT Date, Source, Version, count(*) as NumberOfEntries
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Date, Source, Version
ORDER BY Date, Source, Version
```

If you want to get OS Version per date you type

```
SELECT Date, OS, count(*) as NumberOfEntries
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Date, OS
ORDER BY Date, OS
```

If you don't have huge amounts of data (like several million rows) you won't have any performance problems with suitable indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Here comes use of database [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms). Make sure your DB is in [3-NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).

For example In your case,

Create a table OS_TYPE say it has values

```
Id Value
1  Win XP
2  Win 7
3  Ubuntu Linux
```

etc..

When you need to insert into your transaction table instead of inserting the OS Name,look up table and get the Id, then insert that with other data. Keep a foriegn key reference between OS_TYPE table and DATA table. So for Win XP version-1 or Win XP Service pack 2 you will have the same entry the **ID 1** in the DATA table.

This way you will have consistent data that can be analysed and processed. Once you have the proper data, use **GROUP BY, ORDER BY and HAVING clauses in SQL** to process the data.

Comment: This is great if you know the OS_TYPE ahead of time but what if you ping a system not in this table?  Your insert also has to insert into OS_TYPE as well.  This complicates a database insert to simplify a database retrieval.

Comment: @PaulMorgan : Definitely you don't want to insert the OS_TYPE table at run-time. I think you can easily fill the table with seed data. How many OS do we have now? It can't be more than 10 to 20. Then give an entry for OTHERs too and save that too.